# Layout issues in iOS10

Tags: swift, layout, ios10, xcode8-beta3

I'll try to keep this short.
I was using *viewDidLayoutSubviews* to (mostly) apply corner radius to some views in several *UIViewController*s.
Also doing the same in *layoutSubviews* for custom *UIView*s.

After installing **Xcode 8 Beta**, this stopped behaving predictably.
Some times it works, others works with a delay, others still, not at all...

The one thing that was immediate while debugging was that on first call of *viewDidLayoutSubviews*, bounds are zero for the views in question.
On second call, the bounds are correct; the thing is, as I said, the second call either has a (visible) delay, or never happens at all.

Any pointers?
Thank you all in advance.

Best,
Renato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, just in case someone bumps into the same issue...

As far as I can tell, in **iOS 10** you cannot assume calls performed on *layoutSubviews*, *viewDidLayoutSubviews*, etc. will be called on the main thread.

So the answer seems to be simply wrapping the UI calls on a dispatch block (new **iOS 10** sintax):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Do UI stuff here...
        }
```

Hope it is helpful for someone :)

Best regards,

Renato.

Comment: That sounds like a bug, you should file a radar

Comment: This helped me, but clearly we shouldn't be forced to do this. Have you filed a radar?

Comment: Also, if you move your code to "drawRect" it works even without the dispatch code.